# Python selenium phantomJS with luminati proxy

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to get a selenium working with phantomJS routing everything through a luminati.io proxy with:

```
            service_args = [
                '--proxy=http://lum-customer-<CUSTOMER>-zone-<ZONE>:<PASSWORD>@zproxy.luminati.io:22225',
            ]

            driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=service_args)
            driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
            driver.get(url)
```

where `<CUSTOMER>`, `<ZONE>`, and `<PASSWORD>` have been replaced appropriately. However, requests are not being routed through the proxy. The url is in a bit of a strange format. Does anyone have any suggestions how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the examples on their website, and I would suggest sending `service_arg` parameters like the ones for they suggest for `curl`.

Try this:

```
service_args = [
    '--proxy=zproxy.luminati.io:22225',
    '--proxy-user=lum-customer-<CUSTOMER>-zone-<ZONE>:<PASSWORD>',
]

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=service_args)
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get(url)
```